# How to use mt-downloader module in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

Hello guys i want to use [Multi downloader module](https://github.com/tusharmath/Multi-threaded-downloader) in my project. i checked git link but there is no example to how to use this module. I checked [this link](https://www.libhive.com/providers/npm/packages/mt-downloader) as example and used in my project but its show below error.

```
createDownload is not a constructor

TypeError: createDownload is not a constructor
    at D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\routes\index.js:16:19
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (D:\Project\Mt-downloader-test-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
```

Please help me from yesterday i was looking for some working example for but i did't found it.

below is my code which i used and got above error

```
router.get('/downloadFile', function(req, res, next) {
    var createDownload = require('mt-downloader').createDownload
    var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Gadget_the_pug_expressive_eyes.jpg';
    var path = '/Gadget_the_pug_expressive_eyes.jpg';
    var downloader = createDownload({path, url});
    downloader.start() // returns an observable
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var createDownload = require('mt-downloader');
var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Gadget_the_pug_expressive_eyes.jpg';
var path = '/Gadget_the_pug_expressive_eyes.jpg';
var dl=new createDownload();    
var downloader = dl.download(url,path);
downloader.start();
```

Comment: This doesn't work with mtd check lib directory of [node-mt-files-downloader](https://github.com/leeroybrun/node-mt-files-downloader/tree/master/lib) module to see how mtd is used